# Get data from a sheet attaching it to a displaying array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm really new into this so sorry if not explained correctly.

- I'm displaying Customers Orders for PC HARDWARE in my sheet, form column "A to F". Each with a generic header. (Comes from Orders SS)
- They include Customer Data (Order number, name,tel,deposit,date, etc) and the products/quantity (Comes from product registry SS)

Now in the same sheet- Column "G to I" we insert data refering to each order/product. This data has to be bound to the other.
while

- Orders may have changes in products sometimes meaning changes in num of rows of the order to.
- Fullfilled Orders are not shown anymore

I need the data to stay attached to the corresponding order

[Here a Screenshoot of what the Sheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1iU1.png)

And this is the current Code

```
 function pruebapedido (){

const cajas = Hoja_RegCaja.getRange(2,1,Hoja_RegCaja.getLastRow(),9).getValues()
const pedidospend2 = Hoja_Regseñas.getRange(2,1,Hoja_Regseñas.getLastRow(),4).getValues()
const Hrespaldo = activaPedidos.getSheetByName('respaldo')

//Get Ordernumbers
 let data = Hoja_Regseñas.getRange(2,1,Hoja_Regseñas.getLastRow(),1).getValues().filter(a=>a!='')
 const removeDuplicates = arr2d => [...new Set(arr2d.flat())].map(e => [e]);
 let Ordenes = removeDuplicates(data)

  let array1 = [] //Prodcts
  let array2 = [] //Order Data

 for (i in Ordenes){
  
   //PRODUCTOS Y CANTIDADES----
   array1.push(['Productos','Unid']) //header1
   const productos = pedidospend2.filter(a=>a[0]==Ordenes[i])
 
   for (e in productos){array1.push(productos[e].slice(2,4) )}
   array1.push(['',''],['',''])
   if (productos.length==1){array1.push(['',''],['',''])}
   if (productos.length==2){array1.push(['',''])}

 //DATOS DE CLIENTE----

  array2.push(['N Orden','Datos Cliente','Seña','Fecha'] ) //header2
  const nieto2 = cajas.find(a=>a[0].includes(Ordenes[i]))

  array2.push(['',nieto2[2],nieto2[8],nieto2[1]],[Ordenes[i][0],nieto2[4],'',''],['',nieto2[5],'',''],['','','',''],['','','',''])
  if(productos.length>3){for (a=0;a<productos.length-3;a++){array2.push(['','','','']);}}
 }
Hrespaldo.getRange(1,5,array1.length,2).setValues(array1)
Hrespaldo.getRange(1,1,array2.length,4).setValues(array2)

 }
```

Comment: `Hoja_RegCaja, Hoja_Regseñas, activaPedidos` undefined Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this because I'm not sure about all the data but I think it will work.  Try it on a copy of your spreadsheet first.

```
function pruebapedido (){

  const cajas = Hoja_RegCaja.getRange(2,1,Hoja_RegCaja.getLastRow(),9).getValues();
  const pedidospend2 = Hoja_Regseñas.getRange(2,1,Hoja_Regseñas.getLastRow(),4).getValues();
  const Hrespaldo = activaPedidos.getSheetByName('respaldo');

  //Get Ordernumbers
  let data = Hoja_Regseñas.getRange(2,1,Hoja_Regseñas.getLastRow(),1).getValues().filter(a=>a!='');
  const removeDuplicates = arr2d => [...new Set(arr2d.flat())].map(e => [e]);
  let Ordenes = removeDuplicates(data);

  let rows = [];

  Ordenes.forEach( order => {
      let iRow = 0; // There are 11 rows per order
      rows.push(['N Orden','Datos Cliente','Seña','Fecha','Productos','Unid']);
      iRow++;
      //PRODUCTOS Y CANTIDADES----
      const productos = pedidospend2.filter( a => a[0] == order );
 
      productos.forEach( product => {
          switch(iRow) {
            case 1:
              rows.push(['',nieto2[2],nieto2[8],nieto2[1],product.slice(2,4)]);
              iRow++;
              break;
            case 2:
              rows.push([Ordenes[i][0],nieto2[4],'','',product.slice(2,4)]);
              iRow++;
              break;
            case 3:
              rows.push(['',nieto2[5],'','',product.slice(2,4)]);
              iRow++;
              break;
            default:
              rows.push(['','','','',product.slice(2,4)]);
              iRow++;
          }
        }
      );
      while( iRow < 11 ) {
        rows.push(['','','','','','']);
        iRow++;
      }
    }
  );
  Hrespaldo.getRange(1,1,rows.length,6).setValues(rows)

}
```